# Autoinstall Ubuntu 20.04 using a custom initramfs and a cdrom froma repository server

Tags: 20.04, grub2, system-installation

I want to do an automated install fro Ubuntu 20.04

I'm creating a a bootable partition with a modified initramfs( contains some files that I need later) on a virtual machine(vmware).

This partition is mounted on another server so this way I copy to the partition.

I have the unpacked iso of Ubuntu 20.04 on a repository server.

When I reboot the machine I want the kernel/initramfs from the bootable partition to be executed and later to install Ubuntu 20.04 taking the data from the repository server.

The bootloader(grub) config is set:

```
 kernel vmlinuz autoinstall ds=nocloud;s=/cdrom/nocloud
 initrd initrd custom-init
```

in custom-init I have the autoinstall configurations.

The virtual machines reboots starts the install but after a period triggers a 42 error, is not founding cdrom.

Answer (score 1):

This might be an example of what you are trying to do.

Create a directory structure for a custom initrd file.

```
mkdir custom-init
cd custom-init
mkdir autoinstall
mkdir -p conf/conf.d
```

Create the autoinstall configuration files.  You will want to use your complete `user-data` file.  This is just a basic example.

```
cat <<EOF > autoinstall/meta-data 
instance-id: focal-autoinstall
EOF
cat <<EOF > autoinstall/user-data
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1
EOF
```

Create a script to copy the `autoinstall` directory to `/run`.  The initrd from the installation media will change the root file system before starting the installer (*subiquity*).  The initrd root file system is not accessible by the installer, but the `/run` partition persists after the changing of the root file system.  The files bundled in initrd can be made available to the installer by placing them in `/run`.  This script is a very kludgy solution, but I struggled to find another way to run a script from the custom initrd.

```
cat <<EOF > conf/conf.d/autoinstall.conf
echo 'cp -r /autoinstall /run/' >> /scripts/init-top/ORDER
EOF
```

Create the custom initrd.

```
find . | cpio --create --format='newc' | gzip > ../custom.gz
```

I tested this booting Grub over PXE with the following `menuentry`. I found that I had to put `/custom.gz` *first* in the list of initrd files.

```
menuentry "Focal Live Installer - automated" --id=install_focal_live_unattended {
    echo "Loading Kernel..."
    linux /vmlinuz "ds=nocloud;s=file://run/autoinstall/" ip=dhcp url=http://${pxe_default_server}/tftp/ubuntu-20.04.4-live-server-amd64.iso autoinstall cloud-config-url=/dev/null root=/dev/ram0 ---
    echo "Loading Ram Disk..."
    initrd /custom.gz /initrd
}
```

I tested this using the Ubuntu 20.04.4 installer.