# Autoinstall user-data in initrd

Tags: 21.10, pxe

I am currently playing around with the cloud-init autoinstall procedure.

The way we installed ubuntu or debian via PXE was to start a linux miniroot, get ubuntu/debian kernel and initrd. patch the preseed and pack it into the inird. Then we did an kexec and die installer ran without user interaction.

This is what I would like to do with the cloud-init installation.
Boot miniroot, patch user-data yaml file and pack it into the initrd.

Currently with havin user-data on an apache the installation runs fine.

Is there any possibility to pack the user-data into the initrd and make it install unattended without the need of an apache?
I use a similar approach on Linux Mint 20-X where the preseed is in the initrd and the iso content is loaded via nfsroot

This is the kexec command that works:

```
/sbin/kexec --load /mnt/hd/tmp/vmlinuz  --append='url=http://10.100.1.40/ubuntu-21.10-live-server-amd64.iso autoinstall ds=nocloud-net;s=http://10.100.1.40/ubuntu22-04/ubuntu22-04.nightly.test/ ip=dhcp ---' --initrd=/mnt/hd/tmp/initrd
```

This one right now doesn't

```
/sbin/kexec --load /mnt/hd/tmp/vmlinuz  --append='url=http://10.100.1.40/ubuntu-21.10-live-server-amd64.iso autoinstall ds=nocloud;s=/ ip=dhcp ---' --initrd=/mnt/hd/tmp/initrd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC, the `debian-installer` would never change root file systems.  The new `subiquity` installer will change root file systems and the initrd root file system is not accessible from the installer.

However, the `/run` file system is preserved when the root file system is changed.  Therefore, this approach might work (I have not tried it).

- modify the initrd image to include your `user-data` file and a script that copies the `user-data` file to a path like `/run/autoinstall/user-data`.
- use a boot parameter like `ds="nocloud;s=file:///run/autoinstall"`

**edit** I provided example steps to bundle the autoinstall files in a custom initrd, copy them to `/run`, and use them as the datasource at https://askubuntu.com/a/1399184/376778 .  That may help demonstrate the approach I suggest.

Comment: This absolutley works, thanks for your help