# Ubuntu Autoinstall ISO netboot (PXE)

Tags: iso, pxe

I need to install machines from the network using PXE. I already have an ISO (22.04), which I generated to work with my own `user-data` (autoinstall).

I found some ways over the internet to use PXE with Ubuntu with autoinstall, but not one with an ISO already generated with its own `autoinstall / user-data.`

I have a PXE machine that already works properly over HTTP and an ISO that is located in NFS; I need to know what **exactly** to add to the file that should contain something like the following -

```
LABEL ubuntu-autoinstall
        MENU label Install Ubuntu - autoinstall
        KERNEL vmlinuz
        INITRD initrd
        APPEND nfs:generated_ubuntu.iso
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Autoinstall Ubuntu 20.04 using a custom initramfs and a cdrom froma repository server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1398052/autoinstall-ubuntu-20-04-using-a-custom-initramfs-and-a-cdrom-froma-repository-s)

Comment: Sorry, no. Inside my ISO I already have a proper autoinstall - `userdata` and `metadata`.
All I need is that the PXE server will point my ISO, with the correct keys and values in the PXE file.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is to make your custom ISO available over HTTP.  The `pxelinux` configuration would then look like

```
LABEL ubuntu-autoinstall
        MENU DEFAULT
        MENU label Install Ubuntu - autoinstall
        KERNEL vmlinuz
        INITRD initrd
        APPEND root=/dev/ram0 ramdisk_size=1500000 ip=dhcp autoinstall cloud-config-url=/dev/null ds=nocloud;s=file://cdrom/YOURPATH/ url=http://YOURWEBSERVER/YOURCUSTOMISOFILE
```

This should be just like the examples you've found except that

- the `url=` argument points to your custom ISO
- the `ds=` argument points to the path on the ISO where you have added the autoinstall files.  The ISO will be available mounted at `/cdrom`.